# Who are the people in the news in "Brightburn"?

Tags: credits, brightburn

In the movie *Brightburn*, when the credits start rolling, we see some news clips from YouTube showing Brightburn destroying some buildings and all. Then the guy in the video talks about two people, about some witch and a one-half man half sea creature (Aquaman?).

[image: news report on YouTube]

I didn't get a clear picture. Below is the post-credit scene.

Who are they really?

Comment: They are the reverse of Aquaman and Wonder woman, just like Brightburn who is the reverse of Superman. The guy in red(from the multi picture screen) is the guy from the movie Super which is also directed by James Gunn. No one knows who the rest are because it is not explained who they are

Comment: how incredibly scary would a half-man/half-sea creature which was aggressive and had super powers. this is sort of like creature from the black lagoon if it could also fly and had other powers. but wasn't one of the aquaman-like characters morally ambivalent anyway or at least not unconditionally a friend of humanity?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Collider](http://collider.com/brightburn-ending-explained/#images), these were:

> clear references to Aquaman and Wonder Woman.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightburn#Possible_sequels), this was

> intended to set up a sequel